# How to include Column K != null condition in google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that copy pastes data from one sheet to another workbook whenever I run it. However, I only want specific data to copy from the original sheet where column K is not null. Could someone help recommend how I can incorporate that in my code?

Thanks in advance!

```
function transferList() 
{
   var sourceSheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Colombo");
 var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 sourceData.splice(0,1);  // Remove header
 var targetSS = . 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("TargetSheetID").getSheetByName("Tester");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
 targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);

}
```

Comment: Well, you have to look at the value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate through your data and put all the values the have non-null column K into another array:

```
var targetData = [];
for (var i in sourceData) {
  if (sourceData[i][11] !== null && sourceData[i][11] !== '') {
    targetData.push(sourceData[i]);
  }
}
```

Then you'd paste `targetData` into your target sheet.

Comment: Thanks @a-change - this code worked - just needed to change 11 to 10 since i is 0 and K falls at the 10th place according to that :)

Answer (score 1):

Copying the final code here:

```
function transferList() 
{
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Colombo");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sourceData.splice(0,1);  // Remove header
  var rows = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = rows.getValues();
  var targetData = [];

  for (var i in sourceData) {
  if (sourceData[i][10] !== null && sourceData[i][10] !== '') {
    targetData.push(sourceData[i]);
  }
}
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("TargetSheetLink").getSheetByName("Tester");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
     targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);

}
```

Comment: @a-change - Could you recommend how I can maintain the formatting of the cells in the above macro?

Comment: In a similar fashion: using `getBackgrounds`, `getFontColors`, etc. on your source range and then setting them on your target range, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range