# Date formatting in google-script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to change the format to "mmm-dd-yyyy"(Nov-11-2019) using the code that I have.

Please see below code:

```
    var timeStamp = data[i][timeStampappr];
    var formatted = (timeStamp.getMonth()+1) + '/' + timeStamp.getDate() + '/' + timeStamp.getYear();
```

Current format is 11/11/2019 and I want it to be like Nov-11-2019

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following, then if timestamp is a string it might be of a form that the date constructor will create the date properly.  If it's a date the it just creates another date object with the same value.  So If you're not always sure what you're going to find in your timestamp value this approach may provide you with more consistent performance. Also note the M's have to be capitalize for the Month.

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(timestamp), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy");
```

[Simple Date Formatting Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[JavaScript Date Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Great question, a straight-forward solution if you can't find a more specific function to do the job, is to create an array of the string representation of the months. That is:

```
var monthsAsStrings = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", ... ];
var formatted = monthsAsStrings[timeStamp.getMonth() + 0 ] + '-' + timeStamp.getDate() + '-' + timeStamp.getYear();
                     ^                                 ^      ^
```

Note that array indices start at 0, while we typically call January month 1. The + 0 is not necessary but illustrates the difference between the code you posted and what you're requesting.

Additionally, the '/' is replaced with '-'.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Good job @Simon Jonsson very much appreciated.

Comment: I have a follow-up question, I am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot find function getMonth in object . if there's an empty cell in my spreadsheet. Because not all the data have dates.

Comment: Could be that you are sending in an integer in your function which is outside of the scope, you could do a "null check". Is this not working for any value or is it only for certain integers?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532868/how-to-include-column-k-null-condition-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you could check first if you have a timestamp, before formatting the date:

```
function myFunction(data) {
  var timeStamp = data[i][timeStampappr];
  // If there is no timestamp, then do nothing.
  if(timestamp){
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "MMM-dd-yyyy");
    Logger.log(formattedDate);
  } 
}
```